# Unable to access ASP.NET session object in Nancy Module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nancy

I'm trying to combine an MVC3 application with some Nancy modules.  In my application I'm trying to set a session variable in the MVC3 controller and then read that variable in the Nancy module.  When I attempt to read the variable in the Nancy controller the Session object is null.

Here is a gist of my MVC3 controller, Nancy module, and root web.config.

https://gist.github.com/3105219

It looks like all(most) of the other objects hanging off the Current httpcontext is not null and looks "normal" when comparing it in the MVC3 section of the application.

Edit: Further testing shows that I can't access the ASP.NET session in a raw Nancy application.  I created the application using the steps at the bottom of this page in section "Creating your first Nancy application".

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Introduction

Here is the web.config of the simple Nancy application.

https://gist.github.com/3105583

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `BootStrapper` to provide session services in Nancy. Session services are provided by `ISession` interface. Nancy comes with couple of default implementations: `NullSessionProvider` and `Session`. I guess the default one is `NullSessionProvider`. The other implementation stores the data in process and doesn't uses cookies. To create a cookie based sessions you have to create a bootstrapper as below.

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines  pipelines)
    {
      CookieBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines);
    }
}
```

Ref. http://blog.csainty.com/

**EDIT:**

From my understanding Nancy uses it's own context classes to provide request, session, cache and other stuff. It's the bootstrappers that helps to provide these services. I'm not sure you can use ASP.NET objects like HttpContext, HttpSession straightly as default in Nancy.

Comment: Is that cookie based (client side) session storage and not server side session storage?  I thought this was Nancy's own method of managing state that is separate from the ASP.NET runtime in memory session storage.

When I tried this the Request.Session["First_Name"] isn't there even though it was set on the MVC3 controller.

Comment: A bit more trial and error shows tha I can use the Nancy Request.Session to keep state across Nancy routes but the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session is still null and the Nancy Request.Session is empty.

Comment: @Rob I'm also in learning phase! Based on the introduction I had I think Nancy is not using System.Web.HttpContext. It is using it's own context classes and I guess that mainly to help Nancy to run in any environment (not sure though!). I just downloaded the source and run a search.

Answer (score 4):

Inherit `IRequiresSessionState` to enable `Asp.net` Session.

```
public class NancyAspHttpRequestHandler 
: NancyHttpRequestHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

}
```

and use `NancyAspHttpRequestHandler` in handler registration, this can be possible using `Nancy.AspNet` hosting.

This will solve the problem

Comment: Good answer, not sure why no one else has upvoted this yet - solves the original problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I follow up on the answer of prakash and AdrieanKhisbe (it worked for me - but I had some time to figure out how).

write a new .cs file with exactly that content as stated in the previous answer:

> public class NancyAspHttpRequestHandler  : NancyHttpRequestHandler,
>   IRequiresSessionState {
>
> }

It's an empty class, but it inherits both from `NancyHttpRequestHandler` and from `IRequiresSessionState` (Http Session state).

Then, in the Web.config, replace the `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler` by this new `NancyAspHttpRequestHandler`

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <!--add name="Nancy" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*" /-->
      <add name="Nancy" verb="*" type="your_name_space.NancyAspHttpRequestHandler" path="*" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Now, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is not null anymore.